# How to weight and label arrows created in geom_segment using another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data-visualization, geom-segment

Consider this dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = rep(1, 6),
                   Loc = c("A","B","D","A","D","B"),
                   TimeDiff = c(NA, 4.5,2.2,2.1,3.4,7.2))
```

We have the same `ID` with observations at multiple locations (`Loc`). The observations are arranged in the order in which they occurred, so the first observation was at `Loc == A`, the second was at `Loc == B`, and so on. `TimeDiff` is the time period between each consecutive observation. I made the following plot to show the "path" between the `Loc`s over time:

```
library(tidyverse)
data%>%
  mutate(RowNumber = row_number(), xend = lead(Loc), yend = lead(RowNumber))%>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_segment(aes(x = Loc, y = RowNumber, xend = xend, yend = yend), arrow = arrow(), size = 2)
```

[image]

My main question: how can we weight the size of each arrow according to the variable `TimeDiff`, and how can we label each arrow with the respective value for `TimeDiff`? Meaning the arrow connecting the first 2 observations where `Loc == A` and `Loc == B` will be thicker than the arrow that follows because there was a greater `TimeDiff` (4.2) between the two observations.

A side question:
Notice the 3 levels of `Loc` include `A`, `B`, and `D`. Assume there is another level `C` that I want to be included in the plot between `B` and `D`. How can this be thrown in there?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution with slightly modified data.
The drawback is to hard code `nudge_x` and `nudge_y`:

```
# modified data NA replaced by 0 and last value replaced by NA as we only have 5 differences in 6 datapoints

data <- data.frame(ID = rep(1, 6),
                   Loc = c("A","B","D","A","D","B"),
                   TimeDiff = c(0, 4.5,2.2,2.1,3.4,NA))

library(tidyverse)
data%>%
    mutate(RowNumber = row_number(), xend = lead(Loc), yend = lead(RowNumber))%>%
    ggplot()+
    geom_segment(aes(x = Loc, y = RowNumber, xend = xend, yend = yend), 
                 arrow = arrow(), size = data$TimeDiff) +
    geom_label(aes(x = Loc, y = RowNumber, xend = xend, yend = yend, label = data$TimeDiff),
               nudge_x = c(0.3, 0.5, -1, 1, -0.7),
               nudge_y = seq(0.2,6, 0.1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, not exactly a pretty figure, but hopefully this is enough to get you started. The key is to put `size` inside of the `aes` and link it to one of your variables using `scale_size_identity()`.

So in this case instead of having `size = 2` for all segments, size is controlled by the values in `TimeDiff`, e.g. `4.5`, `2.2`, etc. Note I replaced the `NA` with `0` for the `size` call, and with `"NA"` for the label.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(1, 6),
                  Loc = c("A","B","D","A","D","B"),
                  TimeDiff = c(NA, 4.5,2.2,2.1,3.4,7.2)) %>%
  mutate(RowNumber = row_number(), 
         xend = lead(Loc), 
         yend = lead(RowNumber))


dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Loc, y = RowNumber, xend = xend, yend = yend))+
  geom_segment(aes(size = replace_na(TimeDiff, 0)), arrow = arrow()) +
  geom_label(aes(label = replace_na(TimeDiff, "NA"))) +
  scale_size_identity()
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>